# Nestjs OnModuleInit error on PrismaService

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I'm building a Nestjs CRUD but when I start the server, is logging this error: Property 'onModuleInit' is missing in type 'PrismaService' but required in type 'OnModuleInit'.

**prisma.service.ts**

```
import { INestApplication, Injectable, OnModuleInit } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async OnModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on("beforeExit", async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

**terminal log**

```
    [09:36:16] Starting compilation in watch mode...

src/prisma/prisma.service.ts:5:14 - error TS2420: Class 'PrismaService' incorrectly implements interface 'OnModuleInit'.
  Property 'onModuleInit' is missing in type 'PrismaService' but required in type 'OnModuleInit'.

5 export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@nestjs/common/interfaces/hooks/on-init.interface.d.ts:9:5
    9     onModuleInit(): any;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'onModuleInit' is declared here.

[09:36:21] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

I'm following [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma#prisma)

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnModuleInit` method needs to be `onModuleInit`. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `OnModuleInit` and `onModuleInit` are two different methods

Comment: Thanks, man!!
I didn't notice the capital "O"